# Cannot override default css of all elements style with media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to make one website responsive. the problem is that some elements adjust with media queries whereas others keep their native style...

I've tried different css files but no difference..
It drives me crazy 2 days now so if anybody has a clue what happens plz help.

```
.wrapper { 
    width:1200px; height:800px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    clear:both;
}
.image img {
    width:1200px;
    height:570px;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 240px){

    .image img {        /* this works*/
        width:240px; 
        height:100px;
    } 
    .wrapper{            /*this doesn't*/
        width:240px;  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle for this with corresponding HTML?

Comment: Have you tried to also adjust the `height`? of the `.wrapper`

Comment: yes BigRabbit i tried also to adjust height but no difference...Do you believe that my code is correct?? Do you find something wrong?